# SQL ERROR--EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is my Stored proc, where i think every thing is correct

```
ALTER PROC USP_D_Delete
(
   @ID INT=NULL,
   @RETURN INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRAN

         BEGIN

            DELETE FROM PE WHERE ID =@ID

         END

      COMMIT

      SET @RETURN = 1
      RETURN @RETURN

   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH

      ROLLBACK
      SET @RETURN = 0
      RETURN @RETURN

   END CATCH

END
```

WHen i try to execute this from UI iam getting ERROR as

```
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements.Previous count = 0, current count = 1
```

ANY Help please, i could not find solution as i think this syntax is correct , tryed COMMIT after ROLLBACK Also, its No use..

Comment: Please, could you phrase a question? What does it do, what do you want it to do?

Comment: maybe if you give the transaction a name.. `BEGIN TRAN t1`, `COMMIT TRAN t1`, `ROLLBACK TRAN t1`

Comment: @contradictioned You wnat to give name to that transaction and try?

Comment: See the answer below, the code looks good. I don't have a SQL-Server here, to I cannot try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to add a word `TRAN` after `commit` and `rollback` as below:

```
ALTER PROC USP_D_Delete
(
   @ID INT=NULL,
   @RETURN INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN    
   SET NOCOUNT ON;    
   BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRAN    
         BEGIN    
            DELETE FROM PE WHERE ID =@ID    
         END    
      COMMIT TRAN    
      SET @RETURN = 1
      RETURN @RETURN    
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH    
      ROLLBACK TRAN
      SET @RETURN = 0
      RETURN @RETURN    
   END CATCH    
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but IMHO there is no sense in your SP code as it is:

1. `DELETE` statement is atomic and doesn't need explicit transaction
2. Your SP will always return 1 since if you feed a non-existent id to `DELETE` it will silently execute and just won't delete anything. The only thing can go wrong and lead to an exception is the absence of `PE` table. But in that case you don't have anything to rollback.

That being said the whole SP can boiled down to the only `DELETE` statement